# Undo pending changes

Tags: c#, tfs

sorry in advance for the bad English..
I made changes to my solution which is a branch of the original solution that is on TFS. I put her in confusion, then I made undo pending changes to return to the initial version but I found it full of errors that were not there before.

```
"Error  25  The type or namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace '...' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

"Error  18  Metadata file '.dll' could not be found"

"Error  9   Assembly '...' uses '...' which has a higher version than referenced assembly '...'
```

I hope I was clear, 
sorry again for the embarrassing English

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the solution? Also try closing and reopening visual studio.

Comment: yes, many times, but it not working.
I also tried to change the configuration of the solution and compile without some projects, and then add them again but nothing has changed

Comment: When a branch of a working solution doesn't work and had errors like this, I usually find that there are some file system references that do not align anymore and are not under source control.  For example, if you are looking for a .dll in another project instead of using a project reference.  Look for yellow triangle warnings in the reference lists of the projects within the solution.

Comment: yeah I've found two references with the yellow triangle. it means that the project can not find them, right?

Comment: Yes, its missing or not the expected version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can "Get Specific Version" and forcefully overwrite the entire branch, whether you have changes or not.

- In Source Control Explorer, right click on your desired branch
- Go to Advanced, Get Specific Version
- In the window that pops up, check both boxes for overwriting files that aren't checked out and that match the local versions
- Click 'Get'

This should force your system to be in sync with source control